# Get the value that was just selected from a jQuery Chosen multiple select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using [jQuery Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen) to convert my select to multiple select. When I choose second item, it gives me both the selected items when I do `$(this).val()`.

I want the value for only the item that I select at that moment.

following is my code.

```
$("#languageId").chosen().on("change",function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="languageId" multiple >
  <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
  <option value="English">English</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events):

> Chosen triggers the standard DOM event whenever a selection is made (it also sends a `selected` or `deselected` parameter that tells you which option was changed).

Therefore you can access the `selected`/`deselected` property on the `params` object that is passed in the `change` event callback. In other words, `params.selected`/`params.deselected` would be the value of the `option` element that was just selected/deselected.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ec2g0g1q/)

```
$("#languageId").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var changedValue = params.selected || params.deselected;

  // ...
});
```

Addressing your comment below, you could simply check which property is on the `params` object in order to determine whether an option was selected/deselected:

```
$("#languageId").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {
  if (params.selected) {
    console.log('The option: ' + params.selected + ' was selected.');
  }
  if (params.deselected) {
    console.log('The option: ' + params.deselected + ' was deselected.');
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I know if the option was newly selected or the current selected option is deselected?

Comment: After selecting language from first drop down I load the respective values to second drop down. The data is loaded in the second drop down (inspect element told me) but I can not view it. Am I missing something.

Comment: @Parag If you update [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ec2g0g1q/) demonstrating the issue, I will take a look.

Comment: @Parag When you change the underlying `select` element, you need to trigger a change event: `$("#castId").trigger('chosen:updated')`.  Here is an updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/9hd07bq1/